# How do I access the elements in a hash which is itself a value in a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this hash `$chicken_parts`, which consists of symbol/hash pairs (many more than shown here):

```
$chicken_parts = { :beak = > {"name"=>"Beak", "color"=>"Yellowish orange", "function"=>"Pecking"}, :claws => {"name"=>"Claws", "color"=>"Dirty", function"=>"Scratching"} }
```

Then I have a class `Embryo` which has two class-specific hashes:

```
class Embryo

@parts_grown = Hash.new

@currently_developing = Hash.new
```

Over time, new pairs from `$chicken_parts` will be `.merge!`ed into `@parts_grown`. At various times, `@currently developing` will be declared equal to one of the symbol/hash pairs from `@parts_grown`.

I'm creating Embryo class functions and I want to be able to access the `"name"`, `"color"`, and `"function"` values in `@currently_developing`, but I don't seem to be able to do it.

```
def grow_part(part)
  @parts_grown.merge!($chicken_parts[part])
end

def develop_part(part)
  @currently_developing = @parts_grown[part]
```

seems to populate the hashes as expected, but

```
puts @currently_developing["name"]
```

does not work. Is this whole scheme a bad idea? Should I just make the Embryo hashes into arrays of symbols from $chicken_parts, and refer to it whenever needed? That seemed like cheating to me for some reason...

Comment: can you provide your `@parts_grown`and `@currently_developing` values that you get?

Comment: @Mischa If so... then go on.. :)

Comment: @OMG, Linuxios gave the correct answer already. No need to post the same thing twice.

Answer (score 3):

There's a little bit of confusion here. When you `merge!` in grow_part, you aren't adding a `:beak => {etc...}` pair to `@parts_grown`. Rather, you are merging the hash that is pointed too by the part name, and adding all of the fields of that hash *directly* to `@parts_grown`. So after one `grow_part`, `@parts_grown` might look like this:

```
{"name"=>"Beak", "color"=>"Yellowish orange", "function"=>"Pecking"}
```

I don't think that's what you want. Instead, try this for `grow_part`:

```
def grow_part(part)
  @parts_grown[part] = $chicken_parts[part]
end
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is just what I needed to do! Thank you! I didn't realize that defining a key that doesn't exist is the same as adding to a hash! Jesus, I feel dumb now.

Comment: @user2493615: Don't. You're learning! (When I first read this question, I started wondering if the egg companies had started hiring programmers) (or have they?)...

Comment: I recommend using #fetch instead of #[] for accessing the chicken_parts hash.  Doing parts[x] = other_hash[x] will silently add a nil when x is not a valid key, which is almost certainly undesirable, whereas #fetch will throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Embryo
  @parts_grown = {a: 1, b: 2}

  def show
    p @parts_grown
  end

  def self.show
    p @parts_grown
  end
end

embryo = Embryo.new
embryo.show
Embryo.show

--output:--
nil
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?